# What is “cost of work related child care expenses” and “child rearing expenses” in Arkansas?

Tags: child-support, arkansas

I and my ex have a 50/50 joint custody in Arkansas. I have child one week, and then he has the child for one week. I pay to my ex $1,000 a month in child support, because I work full time and my ex is unemployed.

I’ve been researching the child support law https://www.arcourts.gov/child-support-calculator/ChildSupp.html, and found out I could get extra credit for

- **Cost of work related child care expenses.** I tried to google what that exactly is, but could not find. Is this a “day care” credit. I put my child in day care since I work during the day. Can I deduct that day care credit?
- Child rearing expenses. I tried to google this. Not sure what this is? One example of “child rearing expense”?

Answer (score 2):

Child rearing expenses is defined on the form. It is equal to:

Cost of the child’s health insurance + Child’s extraordinary medical expenses + Cost of work-related child care expenses.

Work-related child care expenses, as you correctly determine, is basically, day-care costs, although it could include any child care expenses that you incur solely because you need child care while you are working.

Cost of the child's health insurance is fairly straightforward.

For *extraordinary* medical expenses the emphasis is on extraordinary.